# Setting histogram breaks in JFreeChart

Tags: java, histogram, jfreechart

I am using JFreeChart to draw histograms by filling a HistogramDataset object with my data and using the ChartFactory.createHistogram(). However, So far I have not been able to find anything in the documentation on how to set the breaks of the histogram. Am I missing anything, or does JFreeChart nog offer this functionality?

To illustrate what I mean with breaks, see the following two histograms generated from the same data with identical number of bins, but with different breaks. Note how the shapes of the distribution are very different between the two histograms, therefore it is important to be able to control the breaks.

[image: enter image description here | height = 50px]
[image: enter image description here | height = 50px]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SimpleHistogramBin`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/statistics/SimpleHistogramBin.html) is a good choice for this, as it allows specifying the bin bounds. Add the resulting bins to a [`SimpleHistogramDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/statistics/SimpleHistogramDataset.html) for use with `ChartFactory.createHistogram()`. Invoke `setAdjustForBinSize()` as needed.

```
SimpleHistogramDataset data = new SimpleHistogramDataset("Time");
for (int i = 10; i < 70; i += 10) {
    data.addBin(new SimpleHistogramBin(i, i + 10, true, false));
}
data.setAdjustForBinSize(false);
```

[image]