# How can I make the desired axis on a chart invisible?

Tags: java, jfreechart

Please look at the picture.

[image]

The x-axis is removed, but the y-axis is not removed. Why? The Java code is down there.

```
ValueAxis axis = chart.getXYPlot().getDomainAxis();
axis.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: Please enter your Java code as formatted text, not as image link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note this distinction between the *model*, a `Dataset`, and *view*, an `Axis`:

- `XYPlot::getDomainAxis` returns a reference to the axis that displays the [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) (X values) of the chart's [`XYDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/XYDataset.html).
- `XYPlot::getRangeAxis` returns a reference to the axis that displays the [range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_(mathematics)) (Y values) of the chart's [`XYDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/XYDataset.html).

Focusing on the domain axis, the result of `setVisible(false)` depends on the [`PlotOrientation`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/PlotOrientation.html). `XYPlot::getOrientation` returns a reference to the orientation, typically specified in the `ChartFactory` used to construct the chart. Because a conventional plot has a vertical y-axis, the `PlotOrientation` is `VERTICAL` for a plot where the domain axis is horizontal, and the `PlotOrientation` is `HORIZONTAL` for a plot where the domain axis is vertical.

In this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29283528/230513), the domain is minutes and the range is number of students.

[image]

In *both* examples below, the domain axis (minutes) is made invisible.

```
ValueAxis domain = chart.getXYPlot().getDomainAxis();
domain.setVisible(false);
```

Result with `PlotOrientation.VERTICAL`; invisible domain axis is horizontal.

[image: PlotOrientation.VERTICAL]

Result with `PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL`; invisible domain axis is vertical.

[image: PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL]

A similar analysis applies to making a range axis invisible.

Answer (score 0):

- `getDomainAxis`: x-axis
- `getRangeAxis`: y-axis

Comment: Not always; the effect depends on `PlotOrientation`.